# In ES6, how do I add methods to a class or object that isn't created or maintained by me?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say, if I want to add a method "myAssign" to Object class, how should I do this in ES?

Do I have to add it to the Object or Object's prototype, which does not seem to be a good way?

```
let obj1 = {a: 1}
let obj2 = {b: 2}

// It's OK but not good
Object.prototype.myAssign = function myAssign() {
  return {}
}

// What I expect
Object.myAssign(obj1, obj2) // returns {}
```

Background:

I'm using node express, and try to get values from req.query and use them to create two objects. "req.query" might has property a or b, or like {}.

```
let aObj = new A(req.query); 
let bObj = new B(req.query);
```

hope to get

```
aObj = {a: 1} or {}, 
bObj = {b: 2} or {}, not 
aObj = {a: undefined}.
```

So I want to create my own assign method.

Comment: Do you have an actual usecase?

Comment: Hi RylandCai and welcome to stackoverflow! Adjusting or manipulating an existing object should really only be the last way to add functionality to something. As @mplungjan already asked, it would be great if you could share your use case for this.

Comment: so you want to add methods at runtime to a class thats not yours?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm using node express, and try to get values from req.query and use them to create two objects.
"req.query" might has property a or b, or like {}.
let aObj = new A(req.query);
let bObj = new B(req.query);
hope to get aObj = {a: 1} or {}, bObj = {b: 2} or {}, not aObj = {a: undefined}. So I want to create my own assign method.

Comment: @Ifaruki or to modify methods already exist, something like this.

Comment: I think you have to provide a better example ([edit] your question). The example in your comment is not clear. Please provide an example input and the expected output. From what I can tell, the real problem you are trying to solve does not require the extension of any builtin functions/objects/classes.

Comment: I agree with @FelixKling - I don't see how adding methods addresses the problem or even addresses it better than more direct approaches. However, I'm also not sure what the expected result is, so I can't say what the best path to take here is.